# "HTTP error 404" ---- a webpage does NOT allow to be read from R

Tags: r, web-scraping, readlines, geturl

I was wondering if anybody can solve this problem in R?

I want to read the lines (get its content) from the following web-page using R functions such as

```
readLines() , read_html(), getURL() , and etc.:
```

https://nrt3.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MOD09GA/2019/107/

(You may be asked for user: U_of_C_R_MODIS & pas: Mas_4033708404 to login).
In regard to login, I am using this code in R, which works well for all other wep-pages, excluding this one:

```
setNASAauth(username= "U_of_C_R_MODIS",password= "Mas_4033708404", update=TRUE)
```

For example:

```
url_content <- readLines("https://nrt3.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MOD09GA/2019/107")
```

However, all these functions give error as follow:

```
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to nrt3.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov:443
```

Or this one:

```
HTTP error 404.
```

Or this one:

```
HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

I spend time to find the solution either by myself or google it, but I failed to solve it. 
Any comments and suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems this error comes from "wget" based on this post: https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/3426  Any comments may help, please.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest Wget version, but R is not able to read the web-page